# How to use FileInterceptor on a websocket? (NestJs)

Tags: typescript, express, websocket, nestjs, multer

I want to use this on a websocket, how do I do that?

```
@UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('photo', {
          dest: '../uploads/profilePictures',
          limits: { fileSize: byte * 10 },
        }),
      )
```

Comment: As docs say: "To handle file uploading, Nest provides a built-in module based on the multer middleware package for Express". 
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload 
It basically means that you can only use FileInterceptor with HTTP (Express only) based applications

Comment: How do I make something similar with websockets then?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use FileInterceptor with websockets.
Instead you can handle your files on the front side and then send file buffer in your message body.